# How is the drilling done along the axis for a typical synchronous motor shaft?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I was looking in google, but I did not find any information on how the drilling was done, I would appreciate it if someone who knew how it was answered. As typical it could be an axis of 200 [mm] in diameter and a hole of 24 [mm]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holes or threaded holes can be done on a lathe.

These are bored or machined using drill bits to start then a cutting tool or boring bar to reach the final internal diameter.

Here is a video of a boring bar being made to give you an idea : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8kmZ-9SjRA